# Insert an angular js template string inside an element

Tags: angularjs

Im trying to put some angular js template string inside an element, and expect an complied output. But that's not happening.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="testController">
    <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="fruitsView"></div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function filterController($scope){
    ...
    $scope.arr = ["APPLE", "BANANA"];
    $scope.fruitsView = '<div><p ng-repeat="each in arr">{{each}}</p></div>';
}
```

The ouput is just `{{each}}`.

So how do i insert an angular js template string (here `$scope.fruitsView`) inside an element?

I have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LfU7/) for this.

Comment: Why are you generating the HTML from your controller?

Comment: My use case for this problem: I'm using a 3rd party library (leaflet) where I want to insert some controls that react to changes in the Angular scope. I'd like to avoid to create the elements using the vanilla DOM API and change them using `$scope.$observe`, since that's basically the same thing as just registering normal event listeners.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

In this case, you don't want to just "insert HTML", but compile it. You can create DOM nodes using the `$compile` service.

```js
var tpl = $compile( '<div><p ng-repeat="each in arr">{{each}}</p></div>' )( scope );
```

As you can see, `$compile` returns a function that takes a scope object as a parameter, against which the code is evaluated. The resultant content can be inserted into the DOM with `element.append()`, for example.

**Important note**: But under *no circumstances* does any DOM-related code belong in your controller. The proper place is *always* a directive. This code can easily be thrown into a directive, but I wonder why you are programmatically inserting the HTML at all.

Can you shed some light here so I can provide a more specific answer?

**Update**

Assuming your data comes from a service:

```js
.factory( 'myDataService', function () {
  return function () {
    // obviously would be $http
    return [ "Apple", "Banana", "Orange" ];
  };
});
```

And your template comes from a service

```js
.factory( 'myTplService', function () {
  return function () {
    // obviously would be $http
    return '<div><p ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</p></div>';
  };
});
```

Then you create a simple directive that reads in the provided template, compiles it, and adds it to the display:

```js
.directive( 'showData', function ( $compile ) {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
      var el;

      attrs.$observe( 'template', function ( tpl ) {
        if ( angular.isDefined( tpl ) ) {
          // compile the provided template against the current scope
          el = $compile( tpl )( scope );

          // stupid way of emptying the element
          element.html("");

          // add the template content
          element.append( el );
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Then from your view:

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <button ng-click="showContent()">Show the Content</button>
   <div show-data template="{{template}}"></div>
</div>
```

And in the controller, you simply tie it together:

```js
.controller( 'MyCtrl', function ( $scope, myDataService, myTplService ) {
  $scope.showContent = function () {
    $scope.items = myDataService(); // <- should be communicated to directive better
    $scope.template = myTplService();
  };
});
```

And it should all work together!

PS: this is all assuming your template comes from the server. If it doesn't, then your template should be in the directive, which simplifies things.

Comment: I want to insert an list (the same list template in my question) in the page, when the user clicks on the an element. Can we handle this use case without doing dom operations in the controller ?

Comment: +rajkamal Absolutely! So I can update my answer with more specific code, is the clicked element the same as the one into which the stuff gets inserted or is it a different one?

Comment: I kept running into this error: `Error: Argument 'scope' is required` using the `$compile` function. I found that I had called the function wrong using two arguments, like so: `$compile(tpl, scope);` and been completely blind for `$compile` being a function that returns a function, and in stead should call it like so: `$compile(tpl)(scope);`, as you are supposed to. Just posting this in case anyone else makes this mistake.

Comment: I see showData but don't see it being used anywhere. Missing something?

Comment: @jcollum It's being used from the view; it's the "show-data" attribute on the div. AngularJS directives are snake-case in views and camelCase in JavaScript.

Comment: I thought that might be the case -- it's confusing though. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This started to lead me in the right direction, but, in order to get it to finally work I had replace the part inside the `if(angular.isDefined(tpl)) {` ...  with just two lines: (remove var el completely)   `element.html(tpl);  $compile(element.contents())(scope);`

Comment: How is that simpler? It replaces a one line solution(compiling the html) with about 20 lines across multiple files. What a PITA

Comment: best solution !