# How to inject $scope in Angular Js Service

Tags: angularjs

Sorry friends,I put wrong code and correcting here.
I am trying to $scope in my Angular service but as obvious giving error-

### ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

Here is my code in service-

```
 app.factory('fetchEmpService', function ( $scope,$http) {
        var editEmp = function (EID) {
                debugger;
                for (i in $scope.employees) {
                    if ($scope.employees[i].EmpId == EID) {
                        $scope.newemployee = {
                            EmpId: $scope.employees[i].EmpId,
                            Name: $scope.employees[i].Name,
                            Age: $scope.employees[i].Age,
                            City: $scope.employees[i].City,
                            Gender: $scope.employees[i].Gender
                        };
                    }
                }
            }


        return {
                editEmp:editEmp
               }

    }
```

And in my controller I am trying to consume service like this-

```
 $scope.EditEmployee = function (EID) {
            debugger;
            $scope.employees = fetchEmpService.editEmp(EID);
        }
```

I googled about it and found that we can not inject like this. But not found any appropriate solution.

Comment: You don't inject $scope into a service.

Comment: Ok but what is the way to do it?

Comment: Your definition of the service has `.controller`. Are you sure its the correct one you wanted to paste?

Comment: No,aditya-singh actually it is in main js file where I am consuming service.

Comment: @RiteshGupta i agree with Aditya. You have a function called editEmp which you are defining in the controller - which is called EmpCtrl. Either you are defining them incorrectly or both have the same name. You need to clarify what you're trying to do or build a plunkr so we can tinker

Comment: Oh and you wouldn't return an object with a function in a controller - that is textbook service behaviour right there

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to have scope in service in the first place

Comment: Sorry guys, previously put wrong code and wrong info. Now plz consider again as I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 0):

[Refer this link for understanding how to pass parameters to service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890706/passing-arguments-to-a-service-in-angularjs)

I think `$scope.employees` is an array of employees.

In the service you are trying to find out the details of a particular employee and return the details of this employee back to the controller.

If this is your requirement,

then, I think most probably you can access `$scope.employees` with the controller.

If it is possible with in the controller you can pass `$scope.employees` as a parameter to service.

Within the service we cant access $scope.

[Refer this to find a particular employee details from a json array of employees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590063/get-specific-json-object-by-id-from-json-array-in-angularjs)