# angular ng-bind-html doesn't work with youtube embed

Tags: angularjs

I try to [jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/N2RgN/4/) with the ng-bind-html.
it doesn't seem to work with youtube embed, why?

```
<div ng-app="App1">
  <div ng-app="App1" ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <div ng-bind-html="youtube">
      </div>
       <p>this is a youtube {{youtube}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

script

```
var myApp = angular.module('App1', ['ngSanitize']);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.youtube = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FZSjvWtUxYk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

}]);
```

EDIT: Originally my example was simplified to just adding a link, thanks to IvorG I noticed that I didn't add 'ngSanitize' as a dependency, after adding the dependency I edited the question to reflect the original issue I was having: adding a youtube embed.

Answer (score 14):

ng-bind-html is working with youtube embed 
you just need to add `$sce.trustAsHtml(value)` on value that is fetching the `<iframe>`  i have modified your code Check out the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/azQIBhnoln5DSjNiPHFK?p=preview) ..for the solution

**index.html**

```
<div ng-app="App1">
  <div ng-app="App1" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <H1>This is a youtube Embeded Video</h1>
      <div ng-bind-html="youtube"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('App1', ['ngSanitize']);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope','$sce', function($scope,$sce){
    $scope.youtube = $sce.trustAsHtml('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FZSjvWtUxYk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');


}]);
```

Comment: This was the answer that helped me, because I had forgotten to inject $sce in the controller

Comment: Welcome...Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to add HTML into your JS, you should sanitize the code ([Why you ask?](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize)). To do that in Angular, you need to require the sanitize module. Add this to your head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

And add this to your module:

```
var myApp = angular.module('spicyApp1', ['ngSanitize']);
```

**Update**
And now I see that you also tried to add the link into the text (silly of me to oversee that). You can find the correct way to do in [this article on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846836/insert-an-angular-js-template-string-inside-an-element). A work around (but not advised) is to ng-bind-html a span element. See updated example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XArtv/3/)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to IvorG, I was able to assemble the following solution ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N2RgN/6/)):

```
<div ng-app="App1">
  <div ng-app="App1" ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <div ng-bind-html="youtube">
      </div>
       <p >this is a {{youtube}}</p>
      <p show-data='' youtube="{{youtube}}"></p>
    <button ng-click="showContent()">Show the Content</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

script

```
var myApp = angular.module('App1', ['ngSanitize']);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.youtube = 'tmp content';
    $scope.showContent = function () {
        $scope.youtube = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FZSjvWtUxYk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    };
}]);

myApp.directive( 'showData', function ( $compile ) {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
      var el;

      attrs.$observe( 'youtube', function ( tpl ) {

        if ( angular.isDefined( tpl ) ) {
          // compile the provided template against the current scope
          el = $compile( tpl )( scope );


          // stupid way of emptying the element
          element.html("");

          // add the template content
          element.append( el );
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**js** code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('App1', ['ngSanitize']);
myApp.filter('sanitizer', ['$sce', function($sce) {
        return function(url) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(url);
        };
}]);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.youtube = '<iframe width="560" height="315"    src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FZSjvWtUxYk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>';

}]);
```

**html** code:

```
<div ng-app="App1">
<div ng-app="App1" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<H1>This is a youtube Embeded Video</h1>
  <div ng-bind-html="youtube | sanitizer"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

This works for me.