# AngularJS - issue when embedding the Youtube video url with directive

Tags: html, json, angularjs, youtube, angularjs-directive

I am trying to **Embed the url link from a Json to angularJs**.

Now i have the **{{video.youtubeid}}** with the output in Json controller has **_kux-YQujjM**

But when i use to call this function inside `<iframe>`, it is not working.

when i use this function inside **P tag** it show the output as **`_kux-YQujjM`**

This is my code used with iframe tag.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="250" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{{video.youtubeid}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Whether i missed anything in my code or Is there any way to get the url to connect with this link.

Any help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's beceuse of SCE that don't allow you for constructs like 'something{{myModelValue}}' although you should configure SCE to allow youtube access

```
.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
   $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
     'self',
     '*://www.youtube.com/**'
   ]);
 });
```

here is a working plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/PZXy6RyiWo60KcIyYh5n?p=preview

Comment: You can also use $sce just the current url instead of defining a whitelist: http://jsbin.com/wevalile/1/edit

Comment: I just assumed he will change the url, and whitelists are best for it

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-src:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="250" ng-src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{video.youtubeid}}" />
```

Comment: I added ng-src , But there is no change in it, when i simply use this {{video.youtubeid}} in <p> it gives the output path correctly as _kux-YQujjM, But in <iframe>, its not working, s there any other way.

Comment: I tried this, but I had no success... I soved my problem with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510891/angular-ng-bind-html-doesnt-work-with-youtube-embed

Comment: This does not solve the interpolation error that Angular returns: $interpolate:interr
Interpolation Error

Comment: `Can't bind to 'ng-src' since it isn't a known property of 'iframe'.`