# Unable to perform $scope.$eval

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-compile

I have a simple string as follows:

```
var templateString = "<span>This is a test</span>"
```

This string is defined inside a directive's `link` function.

Now, inside the `link` function, I carry out the following code:

```
scope.$eval(templateString);
```

My next step is to `$compile` the data and associate it with the scope.

However, I get the error when I do the `$eval`:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax Error: Token 'span' is an unexpected token at 
column 2 of the expression [<span>This is a test</span>]
starting at [span>This is a Test</span>].
```

But if I look at the documentation located [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile), I seem to have carried out the steps correctly yet the string does not evaluate.

EDIT: I am using the following example from the documentation:

```
  angular.module('compile', [], function($compileProvider) {
    // configure new 'compile' directive by passing a directive
    // factory function. The factory function injects the '$compile'
    $compileProvider.directive('compile', function($compile) {
      // directive factory creates a link function
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
          function(scope) {
             // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
            return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
          },
          function(value) {
            // when the 'compile' expression changes
            // assign it into the current DOM
            element.html(value);

            // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
            // scope.
            // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
            // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
          }
        );
      };
    })
  });
```

I am not using the `$watch` however since I don't need to watch any expression and have the template with me already (templateString).

Comment: The documentation does not seem to mention `$eval` anywhere. You should directly `$compile` the template and provide it the scope to create an `element`, you should not need any `$eval` unless you are obtaining that string through the elements `attrs`.

Comment: @musically_ut I updated my question to indicate the example that I am making use of. If I don't evaluate, then any angular expression within `span` tag is shown as it is without evaluating it first... I want the angular expressions (if any) to be evaluated too before I compile it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$eval` is to evaluate an expression, your templateString isn't a valid expression, that's why the error occurs.

You should use just `$compile(templateString)(scope)`, it will compile your template, *and* link with scope, means that all expression will be evaluated with the supplied scope.

Comment: How do I add the compiled template to an element? I mean, after execution of `$compile`, I wish to add the compiled template to a specific location in the DOM - how do I do that?

Comment: Nevermind, I got my answer about adding the compiled template [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846836/insert-an-angular-js-template-string-inside-an-element). Thanks for your answer.