# Injecting service into controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting a compile error when injecting my service into my controller. The expected output of this app should be just the text "hello" on the web page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body ng-app="ddApp">
  <div ng-controller="ddController">
    <div svc-show-meetings template="{{template}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  var ddApp = angular.module('ddApp', [])

  ddApp.factory('svcMeetingsTemplate', function ()
  {
    return function ()
    {
      return "<div>Hello</div>";
    };
  });

  ddApp.directive('svcShowMeetings', function ($compile)
  {
    return {
      scope: true,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs)
      {
      }
    };
  });

  ddApp.controller('ddController', ['$scope', 'svcMeetingsTemplate', function ($scope, svcMeetingsTemplate)
  {
    $scope.template = svcMeetingsTemplate();
  }]);
</script>
</html>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xp5BF/1/

I'm obviously doing something wrong. I built this using some code posted here in SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14846975/753632

Comment: return function () can you give a name to this function and call like this svcMeetingsTemplate.name() ??

Comment: I don't understand. Have you tried it in Fiddle?

Comment: To me this looks like jsfiddle being jsfiddle. If you change to "No wrap - include in <head>" in the dropdown on the left hand the error goes away. Nothing is rendered, but that is probably because the code doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Well there is something clearly wrong. The text "Hello" should be displayed.

Comment: Then you would need to `$watch` on `$scope.template` in your directive and actually do something with it. Give me a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to come from jsfiddle not being awesome when it comes to working with external dependencies. That bit is fixed by asking it to include angular in `<head>` rather than on `onLoad`.

To actually render the template, `$watch` it in the directive like this

```
scope.$watch('template', function() {
    element.append(scope.template);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xp5BF/12/

Comment: @AndroidDev I prefer http://plnkr.co/ because it handles that much nicer in my opinion.