# ng-click not executing when built as a string in link function

Tags: angularjs, timeline.js

I'm using Timeline JS to build a timeline. In the timeline there are elements, I want the elements to be click-able.

In my directive link function I build the click able element content like so:

```
var stringToBeAdded = '<a ng-click="setPage(2)" href="javascript:void(0)">March 10, 2015</a>'
```

However, after the string is added to the DOM, it does execute the `setPage()` function within my controller when clicked. The scope is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the $compile service.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Like this:

```
var stringToBeAdded = $compile('<a ng-click="setPage(2)" href="javascript:void(0)">March 10, 2015</a>')($scope);
```

Look here for more information:

[Insert an angular js template string inside an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846836/insert-an-angular-js-template-string-inside-an-element)

Comment: That worked, I had to change to $scope to scope since it was in the link function