# Angular - How to bind dynamic key to html attribute and have it display the value of that dynamic key?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

A project that I'm working with has an image being rendered on the page through html written in javascript like the following:

```
imageHTML = "<div ng-click='showImage("+-1+", "+parentId+");' class='thumbnail'><img ng-src='{{parentImg}}' /></div>";
```

`$scope.parentImg` is assigned a b64 value later on, and it renders fine.  My issue, is that when there are multiple images being rendered through this same line of code, the $scope.parentImg is overridden for the first image, and both images will have the same value, and therefore be the same image.

I am currently trying to create $scope.parentImg as an object like so:

```
$scope.parentImage[idOfObject] = "";
$scope.parentImage[idOfObject] = b64Value;
```

Then after two runs through the loop, $scope.parentImage will look like:

```
Object
51255135: "base64 Stuff asdfsaafasdfsafsadfdsaf"
43214213: "base64 Stuff asdfasdfasdfsadfadsfadf"
```

So, my question...how can I bind the following into the hardcoded html?

```
<img ng-src="parentImage[idOfObject]">
```

The value of this object is a base64 string as intended, but binding to ng-src doesn't work with assigning a dynamic key to bind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert an angular js template string inside an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846836/insert-an-angular-js-template-string-inside-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

Using ng-repeat is one way of doing it:

```
<div ng-repeat="image in parentImage"">
    <img ng-src="{{img}}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression `{{}}` in value of attribute in angular like this

`<img ng-src="{{parentImage[idOfObject]}}">`

here is running example of this concept:

https://plnkr.co/edit/UbsXAB9ghEqKuIZJEstW?p=preview