# How to make Angular 1.5 understand a expression from HTML string added via DOM in runtime

Tags: angularjs, dom

I'm building an HTML block in Angular Controller to avoid the ng-repeat slowness on large data sets.

I'm trying to add a event handler `ng-click="clicker()"` to the html string and adding it to the DOM as below.

```
document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML="<button ng-click='clicker()'>Click</button>";
```

When this element is rendered, ng-click is not working as expected - On click, no action is performed. My understanding is that Angular is not aware of this element as this point of time. In that case how do I make Angular recognise it as a valid Angular event?

I tried to make use if `bind-as-html` which didn't help.

I'm forced to choose this path due to cons with ng-repeat.

Comment: Search for the many, many questions where this is asked and the answer is some variant over *use `$compile` to ...*

Comment: Thank you.. poor Googling skills.. Found a post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846836/insert-an-angular-js-template-string-inside-an-element